# Hide JavaScript menu when printing

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to hide a JavaScript menu when printing.

I can hide the other items like the header and my rightnav, which is just a list of 5 links, using a print.css, but cannot hide the menu. So I know that my print.css is working on some items.

```
    <div id="leftnav">
       <script type=text/javascript>
       //HV Menu v5.411- by Ger Versluis (http://www.burmees.nl/)
       //Submitted to Dynamic Drive (http://www.dynamicdrive.com)
       //Visit http://www.dynamicdrive.com for this script and more
       function Go(){return}
       </script>
       <script src="menu_var2.js" type=text/javascript></script>
       <script src="menu_com.js" type=text/javascript></script>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
       stuff to be printed
    </div>
```

Comment: If your print.css is working/loading then it sounds like you either are not hiding the correct element or you need to supersede its declaration with `!important`.

Comment: I have tried !important, but it didn't work.
I have checked my div label

Comment: Try hiding the menu on screen before attempting to use print.css. That way you verify your expectation that the print CSS you intend using is correct. Also that script appears to be  _ancient_, supporting IE4 and Netscape 4 layers. I don't intend debugging it!

Comment: Thanks Traktor53. Great debugging suggestion and the kick I needed to use something newer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media query css selector @media print for this.

Try adding the following in your stylesheet:

```
@media print { 
#leftnav { 
display: none;
} 
}
```

Comment: I have done that. rightnav and header are working correctly.

        @media print {
        #header, #leftnav, #rightnav, { display: none !important; }
        }

Comment: Can you try placing your media query at the bottom of the stylesheet. If you have a different stylesheet just for media queries then link it after the main one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `@media print`:

```css
@media print { 
  #leftnav { 
    display: none;
  } 
}
```

Now, in the following Snippet, try printing it:

```css
@media print { 
  #menu { 
    display: none;
  } 
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  This will not show in print.
</div>
<div>
  This will come in Print.
</div>
```

Using Chrome, I just get this:

[image]

Comment: That is what I am doing with the header and rightnav divs.
I cannot hide the javascript menu

Comment: @Ralph Did you try giving `!important`? Is it possible to have a look at that online?

Comment: Already tried that. I am now going to use something else based on Traktor53's comments

Comment: @Ralph Yea, better.